# Do variable-sized elements of statically- or stack-allocated arrays reside in the heap space?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, stl

The following is probably not platform-dependent, but I'll fix it at Win 10 GCC in any case.

Suppose you create an array or vector, consisting of elements that each can be variable-sized, in static memory space in main():

```
RADIAL_UNITS = 1000000;
static vector<Pearl> necklace[RADIAL_UNITS] = { }; 
//each element is a variable-sized vector, which can consist of anywhere from 1-50 Pearl objects
```

or allocated on the stack in main() (assuming the stack space is set to allow at least 1000000 memory addresses):

```
vector<Pearl> necklace[RADIAL_UNITS] = { };
```

I'm assuming that, at runtime, `necklace` consists of `RADIAL_UNITS` contiguous memory addresses, pointing to the `vector<Pearl>` elements. What's not clear to me is in **(i) which memory space the vector elements reside (I'm suspecting the heap space)**.

Side questions I'm interested in as well:

It's also not clear to me (ii) how the compiler knows that the elements are variable sized. Do the STL containers have something defined internally that communicates this? If they were fixed sized, I'm assuming they would literally be contiguously present in whatever region we allocated the array to (the second case, i.e., allocation on the stack , would probably result in a segfault unless the default stack space in enlarged). (iii) Is it possible for me to fix the vector elements at size `50*sizeof(Pearl)` in order to allocate them in the same memory space the array was originally defined as? Pearl types consist of two flating point numbers, so they are of fixed size.

Comment: If you declare the array as a local variable most compilers will put it on the stack. If the array is a (non-static) class member variable, then it will be stored wherever the rest of the object is stored (which might be the heap *or* the stack or someplace else if the object instance is a static object). The memory in the vectors themselves will be allocated of the heap (with the default allocator).

Comment: By the way, "necklace consists of RADIAL_UNITS contiguous memory addresses, pointing to the vector<Pearl> elements" is partially wrong. The array `necklace` will be a contiguous memory area, but not of pointers but of `RADIAL_UNITS` number of `std::vector` instances. The size (in bytes) of the array will be `RADIAL_UNITS * sizeof(std::vector)`. Note that `sizeof(std::vector)` is *not* related to the number of elements in the vector.

Comment: Yeah, my misunderstanding was thinking that the management of the Pearl objects takes place in the array, when in fact the std:vector handles all that stuff and is very lightweight. What I didn't understand was that std:vector itself manages its elements on the heap as dasblinkenlight indicated as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What's not clear to me is in which memory space the `vector` elements reside

Regardless of the space in which the `vector` itself is allocated (a fixed-size data structure for tracking elements in its variable-length array) the elements of `vector` always reside in dynamic memory, commonly known as "the heap".

> It's also not clear to me how the compiler knows that the elements are variable sized. [...] If they were fixed sized, I'm assuming they would literally be contiguously present in whatever region we allocated the array to.

`vector` object itself has fixed size. It serves as an "anchor" for a variable-sized array, which is always allocated dynamically. No special treatment is needed from the compiler.

> Is it possible for me to fix the vector elements at size `50*sizeof(Pearl)`

You cannot do it with `vector`, but [`array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) lets you do it:

```
static array<Pearl,50> necklace[RADIAL_UNITS];
```